# DirectCast error

Tags: vb.net, typeof, directcast

I have the following code:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class clsCellListExtender

    Public Class List(Of T)
        Inherits Collection(Of T)

        Private _iID As Integer = 0

        Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem(index As Integer, item As T)
            'your checks here

            If TypeOf (item) Is clsCell Then
                _iID += 1
                Dim nCell As clsCell = DirectCast(item, clsCell)
                nCell.TempID = _iID
            End If

            MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
        End Sub

    End Class

End Class
```

When I try to compile it, the compiler tells me that "T cannot be converted to clsCell" in the line

```
Dim nCell As clsCell = DirectCast(item, clsCell)
```

Can somebody please tell me what I did wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: you are asking for trouble using an internal class named `List(Of T)`

Comment: Why do I ask for trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that `T` is not restricted to an object. You need something to be an object or in fact any ancestor of `clsCell` class (it's just that Object is an ancestor of all types, so DirectCast always works with it). Consider the following example:

```
Dim p As String
If TypeOf p Is Integer Then

End If
```

The compiler will complain in this case:

> Expression of type 'String' can never be of type 'Integer'.

In your case compiler cannot verify if there is always an inheritance relationship between `T` and `clsCell`. In most cases they won't be one, so you cannot use DirectCast.

The solution for you would be using a different cast operator, such as a TryCast, at least it does not cause a compile time error. Also best if you explained what you meant to do here, because `List(Of T)` is a standard type in .NET, so making another is good for creating confusion.

I would expect it to fail on `TypeOf` line though, using the same logic. Maybe someone else can elaborate on this.

Comment: Thank you, at least TryCast does not throw any errors anymore. I still have some more errors to fix, so I can not test it yet, but I guess it works.